# Infinitely deep folder without symlinks in ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, ext4

It seems like I can find an infinite number of `/pl/locale` subfolders in this ext4 partition, yet none of them are symlinks. Where is the loop?

`$ ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale
drwxr-xr-x 156 root root 4096 May 19 02:29 /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale
$ ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl
drwxr-xr-x 643 138412032 256 4097 Nov 28  2012 /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl
$ ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale
drwxr-xr-x 156 root root 4096 May 19 02:29 /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale
$ ls -ld /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl
drwxr-xr-x 643 138412032 256 4097 Nov 28  2012 /mnt/rootfs/usr/share/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl/locale/pl`

It's an ext4 file system mounted in read-only mode. The image is Raspian but the mounting computer is Ubuntu 14.04.

`$ mount | grep rootfs
/dev/sdb2 on /mnt/rootfs type ext4 (ro)`

Comment: You might have a corrupted filesystem there.  The number after the permissions is the link count - it specifies how many directories are linking to the file. Normally this is a low number.  Have you run fsck on the file system?

Comment: (by links here I mean hard links, not soft links)

Comment: You're right, fsck showed plenty of errors and had a hard time repairing them too. The filesystem was on an SD card, which in my experience are pretty fragile. I dd'ed out a pristine of the original filesystem to the same card and the infinite folder went away.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's comment was correct: the filesystem was corrupt and fsck confirmed it.

Comment: The question was, "how did this infinite subfolder appear" and Paul's answer was: "the filesystem is corrupt". That seems to answer the question for me. What would you like clarification on?